# AtTask Assign category to task

Tags: attask

I noticed that in version 5.0 it's introduced action assignCategory for object category

But when I execute request

```
> PUT https://{domain}/attask/api/v5.0/category/{categoryId}/assignCategory?objID={taskId}&objCode=TASK&categoryID={categoryId}
```

I getting the following error reposonse:

```
{
  "error:
    {
     "class":"com.attask.common.InvalidParameterException",
     "message":"objectID cannot be null",
     "title":null,
     "msgKey":"exception.attask",
     "attributes":[""],
     "code":0
     }
  }
```

what is I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

got in touch with support and found out the reason

I sent

```
> Accept: application/json
> Content-Type: application/json
> {}
```

But body should be empty. Following

```
> Accept: application/json
> Content-Type: text/plain
```

works well for me